# Facebook not adding likes together

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

My website has a few Facebook like buttons on it, however the numbers doesn't really add up. There is one post with 18 likes, then there's the front-page-like with 8 likes and my facebook wall with 3 likes. Shouldn't these likes be combined? I think I'm using the OG tags correctly.

Website: [Rushtips.com](http://rushtips.com/)

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

I used this code:

```
<div id="facebook"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://rushtips.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div></div>
```

Would using this code, make it count on my wall as well?:

```
<div id="facebook"><div class="fb-like" data-href="http://facebook.com/rushtipscom" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false" data-font="tahoma"></div></div>
```

If that's the case, all I need to know is how to do it with the posts, if it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to add post-likes to the page-likes count, which I think should be done by default, anyway..

Using your Facebook page, instead of your own domain, as the data-href is the only way to get the same count on your wall as well as on the like-button.

In posts, you should use the default permalink of your site.

Hope it helps someone.